# Is XY the joint distribution over X and Y?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

The definition of covariance is

$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$

I can't wrap my head around what $XY$ is supposed to be. I suspected it to be the joint distribution over $X$ and $Y$ but I could not find this notation in the respective [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) . If it is not the joint distribution, what is it then?

Comment: It is just the distribution of the product of $X$ and $Y$.  For example suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable which is never zero; then $P(XY=z)=\sum_x P\left(X=x, Y=\frac{z}{x}\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[XY]$ is the expectation of the product of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$. If they are independent then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ so

$$\operatorname {Cov}(X,Y)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X:\Omega \to \mathcal{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathcal{R}$ are two random variables, then $XY: \Omega \to \mathcal{R}$ is another random variable given by 
$$XY(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$$
the product of $X$ and $Y$. In order to find distribution of $XY$ you need to know the joint distribution of random vector $(X,Y)$.